# How Does In Order Binary Tree Traversal Work? C++

Tags: c++, binary-tree, inorder

```
void IntBinaryTree::insert(TreeNode*& tree, int num) {
  //[1] Base Case: is the node empty?
  if (!tree) {  // if node is empty, create one
    tree = new TreeNode(num);
    return;
  }

  //[2] Does the value already exist in the tree?
  if (tree->value == num)
    return;

  //[3] node passed not empty? If less than head pass left otherwise right
  if (tree->value > num)
    insert(tree->left, num);
  else
    insert(tree->right, num);
}

void IntBinaryTree::displayInOrder(TreeNode* root) {
  if (root) {
    displayInOrder(root->left);
    std::cout << root->value << " ";
    displayInOrder(root->right);
  }
}
```

I want to understand why the `displayInOrder` function works?
Let's say there's a tree that looks like this:

```
   5
  / \
 3    7
/ \  / \
1  4 6  8
```

In order to display this tree in numerical order, you're going to want to read the leftmost values on the left first, then the root, and then the leftmost values on the right, and then the rightmost value last.

Now, the `displayinorder` function starts of with an `if` conditional. Simply saying, if the input doesn't equate to false, then keep going left. My question is, once we get to the leftmost value (1, in my example above) wouldn't the next call of "`displayInOrder(root->left);`" equate to the leftmost value of 1 (Which is `NULL` by default) and wouldn't `NULL` make the `if` conditional false?

How is it that this function seemingly knows to not call the leftmost value of 1?

Comment: Have you stepped through it? What happens when there’s no “left” value?

Comment: When I remove all values less than the head(5), and all values that leftmost to the right side of the node, it still works. So, when there is no "left" value, the function call is skipped over. I can understand certain conditionals being skipped over but normally when there isn't input or the wrong input for a function an error occurs.

Comment: The function call isn’t skipped over; it’s called recursively with the empty node. On entry if the node doesn’t exist it returns immediately.

Comment: Alright, I get it better. Let me review my notes on recursion. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yes, the code goes left, left, left, left until it hits NULL and then the first *if* is false and it returns. This is just a little trick to avoid having to test for NULL on both the left and right child. It always recurses to both children and if one was NULL it simply returns.

Answer (score 0):

this is because of the recursion. In the recursive call of displayInOrder(root->left) , the current root pointer is set to point to root->left. But we know that root (for this context it is root->left from the previous call) is pointing to null. So, the if block is not executed and the recursion does backtrack and go to its caller function (when the root was not null and had value of 1).
Then it executes the next line of code which prints 1 to the console. Then similar goes on until the recursion terminates.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It actually calls to display the left child of node(1), but that's NULL or nullptr, we know that `if(NULL)` is equiv to `if(false)` and thus the call of `displayinorder(node1->left)` will not enter the if and straightly return to the caller `displayinorder(node1)`.

```
// stack of function calls
display(5)
  ->display(3)
    -> display(1)
      -> display(NULL)
      print 1
      -> display(NULL)
    print 3
    -> display(4)
      -> display(NULL)
      print 4
      -> display(NULL)
  print 5
  -> display(7)
// ...
```